# Laravel validation MSSQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, laravel, validation

I am using 2 DB connections `MySQL` and `MSSQL`.

And I have one function that needs to save the data in MSSQL DB. But my validation is checking the MySQL database instead of MSSQL even though I have set the DB:: connection on top of the function like this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{   

    $databaseConnection = DB::connection('sqlsrv');

 ...
```

Do I need to set this somewhere else specifically for validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about the validation rules like `exists`, you can set connection with:

```
'email' => 'exists:sqlsrv.some_table,some_column'
```

You can do the same with `unique` rule too.

Comment: @lewis4u if you specify the connection as I've shown and it still uses a wrong connection, try to clear config cache with `php artisan cache:clear`. If it doesn't help, please show the `config/databade.php` file.

Comment: Yes you were right about the `php artisan cache:clear` It didn't take the data from .env file